# A constructor with only 1 argument in Perl 6

Tags: raku

I want to override `new` so that my class can be created only by passing *one* argument to the constructor, no more and no fewer.

```
class MyClass {
  has $.var1;

  method new($var1) {
    return MyClass.new(var1 => $var1);
  }
}

my $my_class1 = MyClass.new(33);
say $my_class1.var1;
```

The error is:

```
Too few positionals passed; expected 2 arguments but got 1
  in method new at test1.pl6:28
  in method new at test1.pl6:28
  in block <unit> at test1.pl6:33
```

What's up with it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Custom constructors need to call [`bless`](http://docs.perl6.org/routine/bless), ie

```
class MyClass {
    has $.var1;

    method new($var1) {
        return self.bless(var1 => $var1);
    }
}
```

There are a few things that can be improved, eg

- one could add an explicit invocant parameter and use `:U` to make `.new()` fail when called on instance objects
- the explicit `return` is superfluous - the last expression within the method will be returned anyway, and currently, it actually hurts performance
- there's syntactic sugar for passing a named argument held in a variable of the same name

Putting it all together, we end up with

```
class MyClass {
    has $.var1;

    method new(MyClass:U: $var1) {
        self.bless(:$var1);
    }
}
```

As to where your error comes from:

Your method `new` is declared to take a positional argument (giving a total count of 2 expected arguments due to the implicit invocant), but the call `MyClass.new(var1 => $var1)` only passed a named one. Note that said method is the only `.new()` present in your class, so if the call had actually worked, you would have ended up with infinite recursion!